# Conditional Panel not working with variables but only with static values (and actually only with just numbers)

Tags: r, debugging, shiny

I would like to hide the button download until the button stampa is pressed, and of course until the analysis is finished.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
source("/srv/shiny-server/makeDataset.R")
source("/srv/shiny-server/functions.R")

username=random_user <- generate_random_username(length=20)
# Crea la UI per la Shiny App
# Installa il pacchetto Shiny se non è già installato

# Specifica il percorso della cartella
percorso_cartella <- "/scratch/"

# Funzione per ottenere una lista di nomi di cartelle nella directory
get_folder_names <- function() {
  folder_names <- list.dirs(path = percorso_cartella, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
  return(folder_names)
}





library(shinymanager)
showDownloadButton <- reactiveVal(FALSE)







# Crea la UI per la Shiny App
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Compose your new Dataset"),

  # Creazione dei box dinamici con nomi delle cartelle
fluidRow(
    # Prima colonna
    column(6,
      uiOutput("numeri_box1")
    ),

    # Seconda colonna
    column(6,
      uiOutput("numeri_box2")
    )
  ),
  actionButton("stampare", "Generate"),
conditionalPanel(condition='showDownloadButton()', downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"))

)
# Funzione per generare i box in base al numero di cartelle e mostrare i nomi delle cartelle
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # Ottieni i nomi delle cartelle
  folder_names <- get_folder_names()
  num_folders <- length(folder_names)

  # Genera dinamicamente i box con nomi delle cartelle
output$numeri_box1 <- renderUI({
    numeric_inputs <- lapply(1:(num_folders / 2), function(i) {
      box_name <- folder_names[i]
      numericInput(
        inputId = paste0("numero", i),
        label = paste("Cell number for ", box_name),
        value = ""
      )
    })
    do.call(tagList, numeric_inputs)
  })

  # Genera dinamicamente i box con nomi delle cartelle per la seconda colonna
  output$numeri_box2 <- renderUI({
    numeric_inputs <- lapply(((num_folders / 2) + 1):num_folders, function(i) {
      box_name <- folder_names[i]
      numericInput(
        inputId = paste0("numero", i),
        label = paste("Cell number for ", box_name),
        value = ""
      )
    })
    do.call(tagList, numeric_inputs)
  })




 risultati <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  # Funzione per stampare +10 una volta premuto il pulsante
  observeEvent(input$stampare, {
    risultati_elenco <- character(0)
    cell.lines=c()
    n.cells=c()
    for (i in 1:num_folders) {
      input_id <- paste0("numero", i)
      numero <- as.numeric(input[[input_id]])
      #numero_modificato <- numero + 10
      risultati_elenco <- c(risultati_elenco, paste("For the dataset ", folder_names[i], "you sampled ", numero," cells."))
    cell.lines=append(cell.lines,folder_names[i])
    n.cells=append(n.cells,numero)

    }
    dir.create(paste("/srv/shiny-server/users/",username,sep=""))
    F=makeDataset(input.folder="/scratch/", output.folder=paste("/srv/shiny-server/users/",username,sep=""), cell.lines = cell.lines, n.cells=n.cells)
    risultati(risultati_elenco)
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Risultati",
      verbatimTextOutput("risultati")
    ))
  stampare_pressed(TRUE)
  showDownloadButton(TRUE)
  })

  # Output per i risultati
  output$risultati <- renderText({
    risultati_val <- risultati()
    if (!is.null(risultati_val)) {
      paste(risultati_val, collapse = "\n")
    }
  })




output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      basename(paste("/srv/shiny-server/users/",username,"/output.tar.gz",sep=""))
    },
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy(
        from = paste("/srv/shiny-server/users/",username,"/output.tar.gz",sep=""),
        to = file
      )
    }
  )



}

# Esegui l'app Shiny
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The main problem it looks like, regard the conditionalPanel, since apparently i cannot really write the conditions in a normal way. If I use static values like 1==1 everything works but if I use variables it doesn't, so if I instantiate a variable

```
n=1
conditionalPanel(condition='n==1', downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"))
```

it doesn't work. Actually it works only with numbers. Can someone help me?

THanks!

The main problem it looks like, regard the conditionalPanel, since apparently i cannot really write the conditions in a normal way. If I use static values like 1==1 everything works but if I use variables it doesn't, so if I instantiate a variable

```
n=1
conditionalPanel(condition='n==1', downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"))
```

it doesn't work. Actually it works only with numbers

Comment: Try `conditionalPanel(condition='showDownloadButton()==1',...)`  in a `renderUI` on the server side.